# When storing a client's BitLocker recovery infromation in Active Directory, is this sent to AD in clear-text or securely?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, bitlocker

I know that when you enforce storing the BitLocker recovery information in Active Directory (via GPO), it is stored in the computer object's [ms-FVE-RecoveryPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute. Microsoft also has some great information on [How to use Active Directory for backup of BitLocker Drive Encryption recovery information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/How-do-I-use-Active-Directory-for-backup-of-BitLocker-Drive-Encryption-recovery-information). However, it isn't clear how securely this information is transferred from the client being encrypted to the domain controller storing this information.

[image]
[image]

My question is if this recovery password is encrypted when it is passed from the client to Active Directory, or if it is sent in clear text. I assume it is encrypted, but for sanity's sake I want to verify this.

Does anyone know?

Comment: If you have a few minutes you could run wireshark or do a raw network dump and use grep to search for the password in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that there's already a PKI pair between AD and your Computer Account, I would assume that it's encrypted using that signature. There's only one way to check it out, but I don't have any bit-locker encrypted systems and I'm not on my network to verify.

Comment: But it's possible for a local user to login to a system and begin the BitLocker encryption process. Does the computer object have a PKI pair with AD and the computer account as well?

Comment: Sorry I meant Computer and AD. Yes, computers are uniquely Identified by active directory and have their own PKI pair.